# http is not working but https does in magento with https enabled

Tags: magento-1.8, http-request

I am trying to open website on http:// and getting

No data received

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

but  with https:// it works. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Now i found the solution here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911158/how-to-clear-apc-cache-entries . i am using APC cache that was blocking . and clear with this below script.

php -r 'function_exists("apc_clear_cache") ? apc_clear_cache() : null;'